# SP13 - Calculated columns indicator based on Choice(boolean) field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, new-indicator

I follow this [tutorial](https://clouddeveloper.space/2015/01/19/show-status-image-in-sharepoint-column/) step by step..

This is my formula:

```
="<DIV><img src='" 
&IF(Available=1,"/SiteAssets/IMG/Completed.png",
 IF(Available=0,"/SiteAssets/IMG/notCompleted.png"))& "'>
</DIV>"
```

**Result is**

- where returned value of calculated column is **Single line text**:

[image]

- where returned value of calculated column is **Number**:

[image]

Where i'm wrong? Thank you previously!!!

Comment: Is your Indicator column is calculated column with number return type?

Comment: View updated answer...

Comment: For Number, it will work. Your image paths are wrong. Try "../SiteAssets/IMG/Completed.png" as image path.

Comment: ="<DIV><img src='"&IF(Available=1,"../SiteAssets/IMG/Completed.png",IF(Available=0,"../SiteAssets/IMG/notCompleted.png"))&"'></DIV>" --> with this result is the same...

Comment: Just try this. Try to check your image url from browser by inspecting the element. Its just url related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Formula:

```
="<DIV><img src='" 
 &IF(Available=1,"/SiteAssets/IMG/Completed.png",
 IF(Available=0,"/SiteAssets/IMG/notCompleted.png"))& "'>
 </DIV>"
```

Reformatted with linebreaks and spacing:

```
="<DIV><img src='" 
 &IF( Available=1
      ,"/SiteAssets/IMG/Completed.png"
      ,IF( Available=0
           ,"/SiteAssets/IMG/notCompleted.png"
         )
    )
 & "'></DIV>"
```

if Available is a boolean you can shorten that to:

```
="<DIV><img src='" 
 &IF( Available
      ,"/SiteAssets/IMG/Completed.png"
      ,"/SiteAssets/IMG/notCompleted.png"
    )
 & "'></DIV>"
```

and to:

```
="<img src='/SiteAssets/IMG/" 
 &IF( Available
      ,""
      ,"not"
    )
 & "Completed.png'>"
```

Now you can fix the path issue easily